# Where does the JVM allocate objects

Tags: object, jvm, allocation

I would like to know wether a Java object is necessarily allocated in main memory or if the JVM can allocate an object in the processor cache also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are allocated in the heap. However reads and writes of memory will of course be cached in the processor. Different JVMs will do different things, but most will have a thread local allocation buffer which means that different threads will allocate objects in different partitions; the garbage collector will then recycle these and (if the object is still alive) move them to a different area of the heap memory as and when necessary.

Comment: @AIBlue: Thanks for your reply. So if I do `int[] u = new int[1]; u[0]=0;` the following would happen: u is allocated on the heap, a cache line is moved onto the processor, 0 is written into  `u[0]` in the cache, then the result is written to main memory. If this were true I would have to avoid small objects doing little.

Comment: Avoiding small objects doing little is generally a good idea, in any programming language.